# Firebase Cloud Storage Caching from Firebase Hosting

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-api-gateway

So my backend application architecture is the following:

- Deployed  Web Api microservice on cloud run (nodejs express app)
- Configured API Gateway for token validation from client (mobile app)

Profile pictures are saved to a bucket and different users access those pictures.

I would like to implement caching as the read quotas on free tier of 1GB per day is low.

I have read about Firebase Hosting that uses CDN but i can not seem to find a way to use it without building a form of a SPA page .html or other relative static contents that refers to a front end web application.

Another way that i read here: [Getting started with HTTP(S) Load Balancing for API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-serverless-neg) is to create a load balancer but i just want to run a small POC for my project with minimum costs, meaning that my app is not multi region yet and i don't have an established domain.

Is there a way to use the Firebase Hosting CDN for my setup? Any other thoughts for this setup?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While Firebase Hosting has an [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest) that you can use to deploy files, the most common approach is to upload files to it by running `firebase deploy` on your development machine. It is therefor best suited for hosting resources that you know when you build the app - and not ideal for user generated content, such as profile pictures.

Recommending services is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but a search for [free image hosting API](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+image+hosting+API) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i wouldn't like to move my logic off the Firebase infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

ok so after a lot of research i ended up creating a cloud function which fetch the data from storage and sets on response headers the cache control key. So on the firebase.json on the hosting configuration i created a rewrite rule to my cloud function. Now successfully the CDN works!
firebase.json:

```
"hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/getPicture",
        "function": "getPicture",
        "region": "europe-west1"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
```

And the response headers of my cloud func:

```
response.set("Cache-Control", `public, max-age=${cacheMaxAge}`);
```

Unfortunately, it seems that i cannot somehow validate a bearer token in Firebase Hosting. Any other workarounds would be nice to be posted.